# Jest and Enzyme conditional testing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, enzyme, ts-jest

I have a react component and part of that has a conditional code block that gets rendered based around the `useState` hook.

```
{show && (
        <div className={styles.detailsModel}>
          <div className={styles.modelContentBox}>
            <span
              className={styles.close}
              onClick={() => {
                setShow(false);
                document.body.classList.remove(styles.noScroll);
              }}
            >
              <CrossIcon />
            </span>
          </div>
        </div>
  )
}
```

Now the coverage shows that this `onClick` statement is not covered.

In my test i look for the `close` class and simulate a click but it comes back with `Method “simulate” is meant to be run on 1 node. 0 found instead.` which kinda makes sense as this block isn't in the DOM until the state has change via another click and is also not in the `snapshot`.

Here's the test;

```
test('clicking close in modal', () => {
    component.find('.close').simulate('click');

    expect(onClick).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
```

So i guess my question is how are you supposed to test in this scenario?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed this by adding a prop in the component to change the `useState` hook if the component has this prop passed

Comment: Just be sure you're following the Rules of Hooks: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html - don't call a hook conditionally.

Comment: Yeah it still meets the hooks rules. Thanks for the reply.